# How can I find all usages of a namespace and its members?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am trying to search a large solution for any usages of a given namespace or its members, say, `System.IO`.

Resharper's Find Usages allows me to find references to `System.IO`, but only when used explicitly. If a file declares `using System.IO;` then uses any of the namespace's members without the full name, only the `using` reference is found. I need to find any usage of any *member* of the namespace in each file as well.

Can this be accomplished in Visual Studio, Resharper, or any other plugin do this search for me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Place cursor on keyword `using`** of line `using System.IO`. Then you can use the normal *Find Usages* (*Shift+F12*).
This works with ReSharper only.

Comment: This works well for within the file, but I would really like a solution-wide method. If none exists, though, I'll accept this.

Comment: The search returns no results for me, even though I can see where the members are present in the file. The statement is `using Ionic.Zip` and I'm running Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @KyleDelaney This is with Resharper. I doubt bare Visual Studio has this function.

Comment: @jirkamat this is correct. I added to my answer now that this is a ReSharper feature.

Answer (score 0):

As of ReSharper 2019.2.2 (2019/08/28), a solution wide *Show Usages of Symbol* feature still does not exist.

Workaround:

1. *Search Everywhere* for namespace: `Ctrl+T`, then enter `using System.IO`
2. Save results in new windows: `Alt+Enter`

   - You may wish to pin the window so that it stays open.
3. For each result, *Show Usages of Symbol*:

   1. Place cursor on the `using` keyword.
   2. `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F12`

This is **definitely not ideal**, but it is a systematic way to get the job done.

#### Update: October 2, 2019

JetBrains has confirmed that this feature is not currently supported by ReSharper, but they are *considering* adding it to the road map.

- [Feature Request: solution wide "Show Usages of Symbol"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRSRP-476499)

#### Update: October 17, 2019

- *JetBrains* has just confirmed that they have added this feature to *ReSharper*, and it will be available as of 2019.3 EAP1.

  - See: [Feature Request: solution wide "Show Usages of Symbol"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRSRP-476499)
- To *Show Usages of Symbol*, use the `Find Dependent Code` option which will enable you to:

  1. look for project references
  2. look for NuGet packages
  3. search at project level
  4. search at solution level