# Check using directive reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

**EDIT3: Question rewritten for future reference, thanks to [BahJiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7163930/bahjiy)**

Is there a Visual Studio (or ReSharper) command like "Find Usages" to find class usages from using directive?

Find Usages only shows the reference of the namespace itself (and thus "the only usage" as per below screenshot).

[image: Find Usages on using directive returns "This is the only usage"]

When I comment out that `using System.Reactive.Linq` line as per below, `Observable` indicates an error that it doesn't exist in the current context.

[image]

I *could* comment out the using directive and check errors like above, is there a better way than checking errors one by one?

---

**Answer: Find Usages *does* it, cursor position matters**

As mentioned below in the comment to the answer, the cursor position needs to be at `using`, rather than the namespace.

[image]

---

**Old question body**
<strike>Is there a Visual Studio (or ReSharper) command that tells me which methods are coming from `SomeNamespace.SomeClass` defined by `using SomeNamespace.SomeClass` within using file?</strike>

I would like to check the use case when I encounter some unexpected namespace.
Find Usages or All References on the using directive only shows other directives.

I could delete the very using directive and check for errors within the file, but I must be ignorant of a better way...

**EDIT + EDIT2**:
An example may help to clarify the situation better.

*SomeClass.cs*

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    public static class SomeClass {
        public static string SomeExtensionMethod(this string s){
            // some implementation
        }
        /*
            More extension methods
        */
    }
}
```

*Consumer.cs*

```
using SomeNamespace.SomeClass

namespace OtherNamespace {
    public class Consumer {
        public void Consume(){
            string id = "someid";
            string after = id.SomeExtensionMethod;
        }
        /*
            More extension methods from SomeClass used
        */
    }
}
```

The question is, when I find some `Consumer` having a `using SomeNamespace.SomeClass`, what's the best way to check where the underlying methods are used?
Is there a command similar to Find Usages to get all the methods coming from `SomeNamespace.SomeClass` under `Consumer` class?

Comment: all visual studio have that feature, just point your mouse to that method and you'll know what class that method comes from

Comment: Yes, hovering over a method would tell me which class it comes from, but not the other way around when hovering on the using directive. It would be quite useful if I could check which methods in the file come from `using SomeNamespace.SomeClass`.

Comment: actually you can.. if it's a dll, you can check on the solution explorer, under references, double click it, and it will show all the methods under that directive

Comment: for Example using System;  you can see in References that there's System  library, double click on that and you'll see what methods are under using system

Comment: I don't think you are getting my question - I am interested to know the exact use case of the using directive, within a file. I do know methods under `SomeClass` and how to use object editor, and thus would question if it's used at unexpected class.

Comment: you mean you have a nested class, RandomClass inside the SomeClass?

Comment: Sorry that part was certainly not clear - added another example. Consider a situation other file has using SomeClass, how can I get the list of methods called from SomeClass under other file like Consumer.cs above? I'm hoping to have something similar to Find Usages and Find All Refernces.

Comment: This is a valid question. I also sometimes want to know what local code is affected by the 'using' directive. Currently in Javascript the import statement always creates a locally named variable for which I can find usage of, but with c# in Visual Studio I wish I could find what line of code in this file depends on the 'using' directive.

It's definitely possible because Resharper grays out any redundant using directives it finds, but for using directive that are not redundant sometimes I want a quick way to check which LOC depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally just check your using. Visual Studio only allow a method/class call from one Namespace. If there are two more more method of the same name in multiple of your Namespace that you are using, Visual Studio will force you to specify the Namespace explicative in your call.

i.e.

```
using Name1;
using Name2;

namespace Class1 {
    class Testing {
        public Testing {
            // this method only exists in Name1
            Method1 ( );
            // this method exist in both Name1 and Name2
            Name1.Method2 ( );
            Name2.Method2 ( );
        }
    }
}
```

So if you see only

```
using SomeNamespace;
```

you will know that any classes that may come from that namespace is specifically from SomeNamespace.
If there was another class of that same name but also in a different namespace, Visual Studio will force you to type in that namespace when calling.

So if you see that you usings are normal and there are no random

```
RandomNamespace.Class1 class1 = new RandomNamespace.Class1 ( );
```

You know for sure that nothing is out of the ordinary.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear. I am not talking about multiple methods with the same name - nor about any implementation of class or method. To put my question with a bit more context, I am seeking to understand the use case of the particular class `SomeNamespace.SomeClass`, which happens to appear in other code my teammate wrote. It becomes even more troublesome if the class has tens of methods defined but some big refactoring work is required. Hope it clarifies my question better.

Comment: I think I sort of understand your problem. I think this may help

Comment: It pretty much say put the cursor on the using statement you want to find references to and use Find Usage.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405461/how-can-i-find-all-usages-of-a-namespace-and-its-members

Comment: Thanks for the comment and ref, the question is quite helpful as I'm after the similar functionality. At the same time, as mentioned in the comment there, it seems there is no other easy way to check the actual method call rather than the using directives. (Find Usages list me only usings.)

Comment: I misread your comment, it was exactly what I needed - thanks tons for your help! (The question has been rewritten with screenshots to make the Q&A clear)

Answer (score 0):

you want to know if a imported namespace is neccessary to be imported, because types from that namespace are used? if its that have a look in the addon "Productivity power tools" e.g. There is an option to remove and sort usings on save

Comment: Yes, sort of. I do use Productivity power tools indeed, it has been a great joy working with it. What I'm after is not quite what it offers - I know that the usings are definitely used and cannot be removed because of that, but don't have a quick view of where it's used in the consuming file.